# PowerShell Core Setting A Printer Online

Tags: windows, powershell

I use a bit of PowerShell to set all printers back to online status:

```
Get-WMIObject -Class win32_printer | ForEach-Object {$_.WorkOffline = $false;$_.Put()}
```

However this doesn't work in PowerShell Core as `Get-WMIObject` is deprecated. But the following complains due to the use of `Put()`:

```
Get-CimInstance -Class win32_printer | ForEach-Object {$_.WorkOffline = $false;$_.Put()}
```

It looks like `Invoke-CimMethod` is the answer, but I can't fathom how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying the help files don't provide you what you need?

> [Invoke-CimMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/invoke-cimmethod?view=powershell-7)

```
# Get specifics for a module, cmdlet, or function
(Get-Help -Name Invoke-CimMethod).Parameters
(Get-Help -Name Invoke-CimMethod).Parameters.Keys
<#
# Results

ClassName
ResourceUri
CimClass
Query
QueryDialect
InputObject
ComputerName
CimSession
Arguments
MethodName
Namespace
OperationTimeoutSec
Verbose
Debug
ErrorAction
WarningAction
InformationAction
ErrorVariable
WarningVariable
InformationVariable
OutVariable
OutBuffer
PipelineVariable
WhatIf
Confirm
#>

Get-Help -Name Invoke-CimMethod -Examples
    # Results

    Invoke-CimMethod –Query ꞌselect * from Win32_Process where name like "notepad%"ꞌ –MethodName "Terminate"


    $x = Get-CimInstance -Query ꞌSelect * from Win32_Process where name like "notepad%"ꞌ
    Invoke-CimMethod -InputObject $x -MethodName "GetOwner"

    Invoke-CimMethod –ClassName Win32_Process –MethodName "Create" –Arguments @{ Path = "notepad.exe" }


    Invoke-CimMethod -ClassName Win32_Process -MethodName "Create" -Arguments @{ CommandLine = ꞌnotepad.exeꞌ; CurrentDirectory = "C:\windows\system32" }


    $c = Get-CimClass –ClassName Win32_Process
    Invoke-CimMethod -CimClass $c -MethodName "xyz" –Arguments @{ CommandLine = ꞌnotepad.exeꞌ }


Get-Help -Name Invoke-CimMethod -Full
Get-Help -Name Invoke-CimMethod -Online
```

So, all things considered above. Try something like 
(this is untested since I do not have an environment to validate it)

```
Invoke-CimMethod -MethodName Put -InputObject (
    Get-CimONstance -Class win32_printer | 
    ForEach-Object {$PSItem.WorkOffline = $false}
)
```